# Call Action Method in all pages using Pipelines?

Tags: mvc, pipelines

Is it possible to use Pipelines and call specific action method in every page?

Im trying to build a Modal Popup based on User IP it will redirected user to user-specific country.

But this Action Method needs to be called from everypage.
I'm still wrapping my brain around how the process will invoke my action?

Comment: Can you please add some more details to your Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most comment approaches is using `httpRequestBegin` pipeline. You should be aware that this pipeline is called not only for pages though.

If you use mvc, you can use `mvc.requestBegin` pipeline

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
     <mvc.requestBegin>
       <processor type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyProcessor, MyAssembly"
                  patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics']"
                  resolve="true">
       </processor>
     </mvc.requestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

```
public class MyProcessor : RequestBeginProcessor
{
  public override void Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
  {
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to call a `Controller` `Action` on every single page, add code like below to cshtml file of your `Layout`:

```
Html.Sitecore().Controller("Controller Name", "Controller Action")
```

Comment: How will the process indirectly call the controller?

Comment: Answer edited. Check "EDIT" section

Comment: Thanks Marek. So I don't need to invoke Pipelines for this right?

Comment: Yes, no need for pipelines. Your question wasn't clear for me

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is Yes.

For example, if you want to change the output of the current request dynamically you can use the `getPageRendering` pipeline with some additional processors.
In a generic case you can always extend the `HttpBeginRequest` pipeline, just note that it is being executed for all Sitecore pages including the shell ones.

See all available Sitecore pipelines [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/mvc-and-pipelines.html).

A classic example of how to extend / create pipelines can be found [here](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/pipelines/extending-creating-pipelines/).